# Adding in one line differs from adding with loop

Tags: c++

I was solving a simple problem that involves the addition of integers with the possibility of obtaining long long integers.

Consider the following array being the input [256741038 623958417 467905213 714532089 938071625]

If I use this structure

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    long long int max = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4];
    long long int min = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    printf("%lld %lld", min, max);
}
```

I get overflow for the max variable (even though I am declaring it as long long int). But if I perform the addition using

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    long long int max = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<5;++i){
        max = max + arr[i];
    }
    long long int min = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    printf("%lld %lld", min, max);
}
```

I get the correct value.

My question is what is the difference between both implementations so that one results in overflow?

Comment: See also: `std::accumulate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation `arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4]` is done without seeing the type of variable the result is assigned and in the range of `int`.

In the second version, the addition `max + arr[i]` is done between `long long int` and `int` and therefore it is done in the range of `long long int`.

Cast one of that to `long long int` to prevent the overflow.

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    long long int max = static_cast<long long int>(arr[1]) + arr[2] + arr[3] + arr[4];
    long long int min = static_cast<long long int>(arr[0]) + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];
    printf("%lld %lld", min, max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++
The result of a mathematical expression has the type of involved variables or constants assuming all the involved variables or constants to be of the same type.

For example, 3 / 4 will result in zero because 3 and 4 are of type int and so the result. And 'A' + 'B' will result in an integer of type char.
The actual implicit conversion takes place when you are assigning these final rvalues to the lvalues.